# How to remove Unicode like English character in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I am new in regex please any one told me to remove English character's Unicode in PHP ? Here example like

```
&#x41; >A     &#x42; >B      &#x43; >C   ....    &#x5A; >Z
&#x61; >a     &#x62; >b      &#x63; >c   ....    &#x7A; >z
```

I used above type of unicode and I have to remove English word. Please see unicode for english word above. please any one told me or guide how can i do that ?

Comment: So you want to replace `&#x41;` with `A` ?

Comment: No i have text like &#x41; that show me on browser 'A' ...I have to remove that

Comment: So you have a string like: `&#x41; &#x42;` and so on and if you echo it you get: `AB`, but you don't want an output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj if regex is a tag in a question your here every time :D (regex master xD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function.

```
function removeUnicodeChars($string) { 
 $charsArr = array('A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'Z', 'z', '&#x32A;', '&#x32B;'); 
 // Add in this array all characters. 
 $str = str_replace($charsArr, '', $string); 
 return $str; 
}
```

Comment: It's work but affect my other words like &#x32A;&#x32B; -- I have to used that that's affected in string.

Comment: You can add &#x32A;&#x32B; in array for replace.

Comment: but &#x32A; if A remove so i don't get perfect output i want. 
&#x32; > it's wrong

Comment: Try to use no 'A' char, use replace by code '&#x41;'. And create array with only codes in.

Comment: I think that already but if regex used shorly complete my task any idea about that

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below:

```
$only_numbers=preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z]/', '', $mixed);
```